# Como se pueden quitar la interfaz de ordenanmiento y la barra de busqueda de los resultados de un datatable?

Tags: javascript

tengo una duda, ¿Como es que se pueden quitar la interfaz de ordenanmiento y la barra de busqueda de los  resultados de un datatable? actualmente estoy ocupando un datatable para mostrar algunos datos y mi datatable me trae por defecto una barra de  busqueda, la interfaz de ordenamiento de resultados y entre otros. Me gustaría quitar del data table la barra de busqueda y el interfaz de ordenamiento de resultados. Adjunto Img y el script del datatable: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
$('table.tablehPlanProgramaCargaNaves').DataTable({
    buttons: [
        {
            //Botón para Excel
            extend: 'excelHtml5',
            footer: true,
            title: '<h3 class="text-centerp-3">HISTORIAL PLAN PROGRAMA DE CARGA</h3>',
            filename: 'Plan Programa Carga',
                     
            //Aquí es donde generas el botón personalizado
            text: '<span class="badge badge-success"><i class="fas fa-file-excel bg-success"></i></span>'
        },
             
        //Botón para print
        {
            extend: 'print',
            footer: true,
            title: '<h3 class="text-center p-3">HISTORIAL PLAN PROGRAMA DE CARGA</h3>',
            filename: 'Plan Programa Carga',
            text: '<span class="badge badge-light"><i class="fas fa-print"></i></span>',
        }
    ],
        
    language: {
        "decimal": "",
        "emptyTable": "No hay información",
        "info": "Mostrando _START_ a _END_ de _TOTAL_ Items",
        "infoEmpty": "Mostrando 0 to 0 of 0 Entradas",
        "infoFiltered": "(Filtrado de _MAX_ total entradas)",
        "infoPostFix": "",
        "thousands": ",",
        "lengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ Entradas",
        "loadingRecords": "Cargando...",
        "processing": "Procesando...",
        "search": "Buscar:",
        "zeroRecords": "Sin resultados encontrados",
        "paginate": {
        "first": "Primero",
        "last": "Ultimo",
        "next": "Siguiente",
        "previous": "Anterior"
    }}
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No estoy seguro a que te refieres con los filtros. Si a la interfaz que permite hacer ordenamiento en cada una de las columnas o al `dropdown` que te permite decidir cuantos elementos se muestran por página.

Sin embargo, las opciones a tomar en cuenta son:

1. `searching`: Activa o desactiva la barra de búsqueda.
2. `bLengthChange`: Activa o desactiva el `dropdown` para seleccionar cuantos elementos mostrar por página.
3. `bSort`: Activa o desactiva la interfaz de ordenamiento de las columnas.

   ```
   $('table.tablehPlanProgramaCargaNaves').DataTable({
       searching: false,
       bLengthChange: false,
       bSort: false,
       buttons: [
           {
               //Botón para Excel
               extend: 'excelHtml5',
               footer: true,
               title: '<h3 class="text-centerp-3">HISTORIAL PLAN PROGRAMA DE CARGA</h3>',
               filename: 'Plan Programa Carga',

               //Aquí es donde generas el botón personalizado
               text: '<span class="badge badge-success"><i class="fas fa-file-excel bg-success"></i></span>'
           },

           //Botón para print
           {
               extend: 'print',
               footer: true,
               title: '<h3 class="text-center p-3">HISTORIAL PLAN PROGRAMA DE CARGA</h3>',
               filename: 'Plan Programa Carga',
               text: '<span class="badge badge-light"><i class="fas fa-print"></i></span>',
           }
       ],

       language: {
           "decimal": "",
           "emptyTable": "No hay información",
           "info": "Mostrando _START_ a _END_ de _TOTAL_ Items",
           "infoEmpty": "Mostrando 0 to 0 of 0 Entradas",
           "infoFiltered": "(Filtrado de _MAX_ total entradas)",
           "infoPostFix": "",
           "thousands": ",",
           "lengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ Entradas",
           "loadingRecords": "Cargando...",
           "processing": "Procesando...",
           "search": "Buscar:",
           "zeroRecords": "Sin resultados encontrados",
           "paginate": {
           "first": "Primero",
           "last": "Ultimo",
           "next": "Siguiente",
           "previous": "Anterior"
       }}
   });
   ```

Comment: Hola @Jacobo, perdón he formulado mal la pregunta, pero tu respuesta me ha ayudadi, muchas gracias!